# MongoDB aggregate - using $filter with $in condition for projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.getCollection('regions').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'status': 1 },
    { $project: {
        names: { $filter: {
            input: '$names',
            as: 'name',
            cond: {$or: [
                { $eq: ['$$name.lang', 'de'] },
                { $eq: ['$$name.lang', 'en'] },
                { $eq: ['$$name.lang', 'es'] },
                ]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

Is it possible to replace the $or condition with a single $in: ['de', 'en', 'es'] condition ?

This does not work:

```
db.getCollection('regions').aggregate([
{ $match: { 'osm.parent': 0, 'osm.admin_level': 2 }},
{ $project: {
    osm: 1,
    names: { $filter: {
        input: '$names',
        as: 'name',
        cond: { $in: [ '$$name.lang', ['de','en','es'] ]}
    }}
}}
```

])

Comment: What is your mongo version ? This should work in 3.4. Can you add a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: Mongo version is 3.2.9. Ah, this is **New in version 3.4**. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
{ $unwind : "$name" }
{ $match : { "$name.lang" : { "$in" : [ "de", "en", "es"] } }}
```

Rather than use `$filter` inside your projection.

```
db.getCollection('regions').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'osm.parent': 0, 'osm.admin_level': 2 } },
    { $unwind : "$name" },
    { $match : { "$name.lang" : { "$in" : [ "de", "en", "es"] } } },
    { $project: { osm: 1, "name.lang": 1 } }
])
```